# User.Identity.GetUserId() always returns null in controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iidentity

I needed to use current logged in user id in controller. It always returns null. I am already logged in. Here's my code.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

I tried adding the reference

```
 using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

I also tried adding a claim

```
public const string UserId = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2014/03/mystuff/claims/UserId";
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, Id));
```

When I try to retrieve the claim, it gives null as well.

```
(identity as ClaimsIdentity).FirstOrNull(CustomClaimTypes.UserId);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Additional Info requested in comments:**

It's the normal login provided by aspnetuser.

```
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

[Request.IsAuthenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKojE.png) returns true.

Claims added here.

```
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, Id));

        return userIdentity;
    }
```

[Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqSTW.png)

Comment: How do you sign-in?

Comment: Edited my question with login information.

Comment: If you test Request.IsAuthenticated does that return true or false?

Comment: Request.IsAuthenticated returns True

Comment: Is this in the same request as you are logging in, or a subsequent one?

Comment: Where does this code located `userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, Id));`?

Comment: Can you check whether an auth cookie is being set from the browser?

Comment: @AlanBuchanan It's a subsequent request.

Comment: @lbrahim added the image for cookies in the question.

Comment: When you call User.Identity.GetUserId(), are you still in the same Request where the user logged in?  If yes, User.Identity.GetUserId() will always return null, since that property is set in the context of the current request, and when the current request began there was no one logged in.

Comment: login action completed. It's a new action from the page to display a table based on the user.

Comment: I still couldnt find the answer and someone downvoted the question, no sure why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer, I managed to get it work.

I just moved the `User.Identity.GetUserId();` to a helper class method.

I just want to reiterate, the request is not the login request. Its a separate request after the login.

Thank you guys for your time.